# Add "This is spam" as option for recommending deletion in the LQP Queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

More then once now it happened to me that I found a post that is clearly spam while reviewing Answers in the LQP Queue and subsequently had to go to the question, seek out the Answer (often among many) and manually spam flag it. Currently there is no way to flag something for spam directly from the recommend deletion button in the LQP Queue. I think adding it would make flagging spam directly easier.

To clarify: The closest thing to "This is spam" currently available in the LQP Queue is "This is a link only answer (but not spam)", so it distinctly doesn't serve the purpose of flagging something as spam.

Comment: If it's spam, it shouldn't have been in the LQP queue to begin with, but flagged as such.